# How to access to parent class properties inside embedded code block?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a user control that inherits from another user control like so:

```
public partial class UserControlBase
{
    protected Vehicle _vehicle { get; private set; }
}

public partial class SpecificUserControl : UserControlBase
{
    // Vehicle is visible and accessible here... DUH.
}
```

However, when I try to databind vehicle properties inside inline code blocks, I get error: **_vehicle doesn't exist in this context.**

**SpecificUserControl.ascx**

```
<span><%# _vehicle.Brand %></span>
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

The culprit was Visual Studio, 2013 in my case, glitch. Once restarted, everything worked smoothly.

Comment: Yep, just like "kicking the tire" helps with car, same works here :D

Comment: I just had this same problem.  After 20 minutes of googling and debugging, i tried your restart Visual Studio 2013 solution, and it worked.

Comment: That is my #1 step since the day I fixed this issue :D